# Solving for X with different exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't know if I'm just not able to think about this correctly or if this is actually a confusing problem, but is there any way to solve for x (real solutions) in the following equation:

$c = \frac{d}{x^t} + \frac{e}{x^k}$

Where everything but x is a constant. I've tried a lot of ways using exponent rules, logs, etc and have yet to come up with anything. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this has a closed form solution, but you can simplify it into a polynomial:

WLOG let $t\geq k$ - multiply the equation by $x^t$:

$$cx^t = d+ex^{t-k}$$

$$cx^t-ex^{t-k}-d=0$$

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick help! I really appreciate it. I kind of thought that was the case, hmm...

Comment: There might be a "closed form" with some special functions, but I'm not sure, and I'm fairly certain that there's a good way to approximate the roots. Don't give up yet!